# Json api using HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, api, windows-10-universal

How to get currency rates from this specific JSON API? I have used this code for different APIs and it worked fine, but with this API I dont know how to get currency values.

For example this api: `http://api.fixer.io/latest` works and this one in code  does not.

I see that they are different but dont know why and what is difference.

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pretvornik
{
   public class Pozovi
   {  
        public async static Task<RootObject> Dohvati()
        {        
            var otvaranje = new HttpClient();
            var url = String.Format("http://hnbex.eu/api/v1/rates/daily/");
            var odgovor = await otvaranje.GetAsync(url);
            var rezultat = await odgovor.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var serija = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

            var memstr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rezultat));
            var podatci = (RootObject)serija.ReadObject(memstr);
            return podatci;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class RootObject
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string selling_rate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string buying_rate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string median_rate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int unit_value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
[{"selling_rate": "5.152699", "buying_rate": "5.121875", "median_rate": "5.137287", "currency_code": "AUD", "unit_value": 1}, {"selling_rate": "5.156900", "buying_rate": "5.126052", "median_rate": "5.141476", "currency_code": "CAD", "unit_value": 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json response you are getting is an array however when you setup the `DataContractJsonSerializer` you are expecting a single object that matches `RootObject`. Change it to

`new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<RootObject>))`

You will also need to change the ReadObject line also to:

```
(List<RootObject>)serija.ReadObject(memstr);
```

Finally you will need to change the return type of the method to: `Task<List<RootObject>>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i am getting "Task<List<RootObject>>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context", can you help me with that too?

Comment: The code with the changes works fine for me. Is this happening where the method `Dohvati` is called?

Comment: I dont have return in Task<RootObject> Dohvati(string a){}. Thanks a lot for help:)

Comment: That method signature is different from the one in the question is that the one thats now giving an error? Or is the one in the question suppose to take a string?

Comment: I am getting error  in  Task<RootObject> Dohvati(){} so I have tried Task<RootObject> Dohvati(string a){} , but still can't set return. Can you post your code? Thanks

Comment: Change `Task<RootObject>` to `Task<List<RootObject>> Dohvati(){}` that should work.

Comment: It works now, no error. Thanks a million. I still have to figure out how to get values. Once again, thanks a lot.